# Solr 5.x Edge N-Gram filter from back side

Tags: solr

I am facing a problem with Edge N-Gram Filter in Solr 5.x. I want n-grams from back side. When I set side ="back" solr core throws error. For now I am using N-Gram Filter. Please suggest .

Thanks
Shruti suri

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 1):

Attribute side has been removed.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3907

EdgeNGramFilterFactory does not have any argument like that

Its has two arguments

```
minGramSize: (integer, default 1) The minimum gram size.
maxGramSize: (integer, default 1) The maximum gram size.
```

please check here

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter

But you can try tokenizer here

which has a option of side

```
minGramSize: (integer, default is 1) The minimum n-gram size, must be > 0.
maxGramSize: (integer, default is 1) The maximum n-gram size, must be >= minGramSize.
side: ("front" or "back", default is "front") Whether to compute the n-grams from the beginning (front) of the text or from the end (back).
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-EdgeN-GramTokenizer

Comment: Nice catch Abhijit ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, But I want both front and back side. If I use     <tokenizer class="solr.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="front" side="back"/>
It throws error. Is it possible or should I use NGramFilterFactory

Comment: try having tokenizer as side = 'back' and then add the filter which will be bydefault work as side = 'front'...

Comment: or you can think of indexing same fields with two different fieldtype...one field type will have EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory as side = 'front' and other you can have side='back'...